# Memory management semantics of Objective C "new"

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

Is "new" an equivalent of "alloc init" or "alloc init autorelease"?

I cannot seem to find it in any tutorial or article that deals with Cocoa memory management.

Thanks for advise.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719877/use-of-alloc-init-instead-of-new-objective-c

Answer (score 9):

How about [this one](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/MemoryMgmt/Articles/mmRules.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000994-BAJHFBGH). Read them, understand them, they're simple.

Comment: +1 Please, please, please go read the Memory Management Guide for Cocoa. Then read it again.

Comment: Also, the docs on `+new` in this one: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSObject_Class/Reference/Reference.html

Answer (score 3):

new returns an object with a retain count of 1, just like [[alloc] init]. The object is not autoreleased.

Answer (score 1):

`+[NSObject new]` is functionally equivalent to `+[NSObject alloc]` followed by `-[NSObject init]` (i.e. `[[alloc] init]`).

To answer your question, from the `NSObject` class docs:

> If you are using managed memory (not
>   garbage collection), this method
>   retains the object before returning
>   it. The returned object is not
>   autoreleased. The invoker of this
>   method is responsible for releasing
>   the returned object, using either
>   release or autorelease.

Using `new` is rare in modern Cocoa code. Most Cocoa developers favor explicit, clear code over saving a couple of key strokes. Thus `alloc/init` is preferred.

Comment: Here is what the Cocoa documentation on `NSObject +new` says: *Allocates a new instance of the receiving class, sends it an init message, and returns the initialized object... This method is a combination of alloc and init...*  If that's scarily inexplicit, there can't be much that is explicit.