# Cocoa naming scheme for assign initializer

Tags: cocoa, naming-conventions

For some reason I thought this was valid under the memory management naming rules:

```
Bar *bar = [Bar new];
[Foo fooWithNewBar:bar];
// no need to release bar, foo took ownership
```

However now I'm running my static analysis, it thinks there's a potential leak everytime I did this.

I see there is `__attribute((ns_consumed))` which I could use on the `fooWithNewBar` declaration. But Xcode 4.0.1's Clang does not yet support this attribute.

So, there's no such naming pattern?

Comment: Thanks everyone who answered so far and described *basic* memory management in Cocoa and the rules of it. I didn't ask for any of that. I wanted to know if there was an acceptable pattern for transferring ownership in an initializer. My reasons for this are stylistic. I am trying to save repeated typing of autorelease in lines that are already too long and very numerous in this codebase, and rewriting Bar to use `+(id)className` initializers is not an easy undertaking as it has 50 subclasses.

Comment: Annoying subtlety: if `Foo` is `nil`, it *cannot* take ownership! For instance methods, this is fairly obvious; for class methods, this might happen if you're e.g. using a class in iOS 6 but running on iOS 5. It's not a generally safe thing to do; I'd avoid it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I also think there’s no naming pattern corresponding to `ns_consumed` in your case. Naming patterns are largely driven by NeXTSTEP/Apple and I can’t think of a method in Apple’s frameworks with the same semantics you want.

Note, however, that [you can tell Xcode to use a more recent version of Clang Static Analyser](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/xcode.html) that supports the `ns_consumed` attribute, which was released with [checker-254](http://clang-analyzer.llvm.org/release_notes.html#checker_254).

I’m using checker-256 (released today, but any version >= 254 should work) and I’ve just tried the following:

```
// MyClass.h
#ifndef __has_feature      // Optional.
#define __has_feature(x) 0 // Compatibility with non-clang compilers.
#endif

#ifndef NS_CONSUMED
#if __has_feature(attribute_ns_consumed)
#define NS_CONSUMED __attribute__((ns_consumed))
#else
#define NS_CONSUMED
#endif
#endif

@interface MyClass : NSObject {
@private
    NSString *_string;
}
+ (MyClass *)myClassWithNewStringConsumed:(NSString *) NS_CONSUMED string NS_RETURNS_RETAINED;
+ (MyClass *)myClassWithNewString:(NSString *)string NS_RETURNS_RETAINED;
@end
```

and

```
// MyClass.m
#import "MyClass.h"

@implementation MyClass

+ (MyClass *)myClassWithNewStringConsumed:(NSString *)string {
    MyClass *o = [MyClass new];
    if (o) o->_string = string;
    return o;
}

+ (MyClass *)myClassWithNewString:(NSString *)string {
    MyClass *o = [MyClass new];
    if (o) o->_string = string;
    return o;
}

@end
```

This code gives a static analyser warning for a potential leak of the string stored in `s`:

```
// SomewhereElse.m
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",
    [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier]];
MyClass *o = [MyClass myClassWithNewString:s];
[o release];
```

whereas this code, which uses the method parameter with an `ns_consumed` attribute, doesn’t give a static analyser warning:

```
// SomewhereElse.m
NSString *s = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%d",
    [[NSProcessInfo processInfo] processIdentifier]];
MyClass *o = [MyClass myClassWithNewStringConsumed:s];
[o release];
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no such pattern. Wherever I think I read about it, I didn't.

Comment: If you're trying to use this for `assign` properties, you still need to release the object you created at some point in your code.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not trying to use this for `assign` properties, I was just using that as example of how I wanted the `Foo` initializer to deal with the receiving portion of taking the `Bar` instance.

Answer (score 0):

```
Bar *bar = [Bar new];
```

You own bar.

```
[Foo fooWithNewBar:bar];
```

If this wants to own bar, it should be retaining it. That doesn't relinquish your ownership, so you still have to release bar.

I've never seen the pattern you're using.

Comment: I'm looking for a naming pattern that transfers ownership, as though it was assigned to a (assign) property later. I understand the Cocoa memory ownership rules that you describe.

Answer (score -1):

Foo took an interest in Bar, but *bar still has interest until `[bar release]` that interest.

Comment: I don't think you understood the question.

Comment: `new` is just a substitute for [alloc/init](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719877/use-of-alloc-init-instead-of-new-objective-c)

Comment: I still don't think you understand the question.

Answer (score -1):

Ownership in Objective-C reference-counted memory management is C++ `share_ptr`, rather than `auto_ptr` style. In other words, you don't *transfer* ownership to the `Foo` instance. Rather the `Foo` instance declares a share of ownerhsip in your `Bar` instance (leaving you, the caller of `[Bar new]` with a share of ownership as well). You always need to relinquish your ownership share of an instance before it *may* be deallocated. Thus, your example should be

```
Bar *bar = [[Bar alloc] init]; //Most Obj-C devs prefer alloc/init. When in Rome...
[Foo fooWithNewBar:[bar autorelease]]; //relinquish ownership of bar
```

Note that you have to use `-autorelease` rather than `-release` to relinquish your ownership share because `Foo` needs a chance to claim an ownership stake before `bar` is deallocated.