# Convert a string into an int

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, ios4

I'm having trouble converting a string into an integer. I googled it but all I can find is how to convert an int into a string. Does anyone know how to do it the other way around? Thanks.

Answer (score 266, accepted):

See the [NSString Class Reference](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/intValue).

```
NSString *string = @"5";
int value = [string intValue];
```

Answer (score 22):

How about

```
[@"7" intValue];
```

Additionally if you want an `NSNumber` you could do

```
NSNumberFormatter *numberFormatter = [[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init];
[numberFormatter numberFromString:@"7"];
```

Comment: good lord NSNumberFormatter is complex ... i mean "feature complete".

Comment: Watch out - in iOS7 `numberFromString` seems to be an _instance_ method rather than a _class_ one, so you should do `[[NSNumberFormatter new] numberFromString:@"7"];` instead.

Comment: @mgarciaisaia shouldn't we do `[[[NSNumberFormatter alloc] init] numberFromString:@"7"];` as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719877/use-of-alloc-init-instead-of-new

Answer (score 3):

I use:

```
NSInteger stringToInt(NSString *string) {
    return [string integerValue];
}
```

And vice versa:

```
NSString* intToString(NSInteger integer) {
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", integer];
}
```

Comment: check your return value.  NSString*

Comment: I am using data pulled from NSUserDefaults so what should I put after the NSString *string =

Comment: Will either of these actually work? Surely the definitions need a semi colon or you will crash with `unrecognized selector` because you will actually be sending `@selector(intToString:)` not `@selector(intToString)`. Surely it should be like this instead `- (NSInteger) stringToInt:(NSString *)string;` and `- (NSString *)intToString:(NSInteger)integer;`

Comment: They're both C functions. It needs to be `NSString *` though, like @David said.

Comment: @Espresso cheers I have no background in C so makes more sense now

Comment: I hand wrote it rather than running it through Xcode, thats why the * was missing.

Comment: +1 for being the only answer that correctly uses integerValue instead of intValue which is better able to handle the difference between 32-bit and 64-bit architectures.

Answer (score 2):

**This is the simple solution for converting string to int**

```
NSString *strNum = @"10";
int num = [strNum intValue];
```

but when you are *getting value from the textfield* then,

```
int num = [txtField.text intValue];
```

where **txtField** is an outlet of **UITextField**

Answer (score 2):

Swift 3.0:

```
Int("5")
```

or

```
let stringToConvert = "5"
Int(stringToConvert)
```

Answer (score 1):

I had to do something like this but wanted to use a getter/setter for mine. In particular I wanted to return a long from a textfield. The other answers all worked well also, I just ended up adapting mine a little as my school project evolved.

```
long ms = [self.textfield.text longLongValue];
return ms;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = /* Assume this exists. */;
int value = [string intValue];
```

Comment: I am using data pulled from NSUserDefaults so what should I put after the NSString *string =

Comment: NSString *string = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] stringForKey:@"YOUR_KEY"];

Answer (score 0):

Very easy..

`int (name of integer) = [(name of string, no ()) intValue];`

Answer (score 0):

Yet another way: if you are working with a C string, e.g. const char *, C native `atoi()` is more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

You can also use like :

`NSInteger getVal = [self.string integerValue];`

Answer (score 0):

To convert an **String** number to an **Int**, you should do this:

```
let stringNumber = "5"
let number = Int(stringNumber)
```

Comment: This is an exact duplicate of an existing answer.