# New and delete command of c++ in obj-c

Tags: c++, objective-c, new-operator, delete-operator

I have an NSMutablearray of objects. the number of objects is set by user. in c++ I would use a for cycle and the 'new' command.something like this:

```
int fromuser, a;
for(a=0;a<fromuser;a++){
  array addobject:(new class obj) 
}
```

what do I need to do in obj c since there is no new?

Comment: Actually, there is a `new` in Cocoa: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719877/use-of-alloc-init-instead-of-new-objective-c

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would utilize the `alloc` and `init` (or more specialized initializer) provided by [`NSObject`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/nsobject_Class/Reference/Reference.html).

For example, something like the following should work:

```
int fromuser, a;
NSMutableArray objectArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] initWithCapacity:fromuser];
for (a = 0; a < fromuser; a++)
{
    MyObject *obj = [[MyObject alloc] init];
    [objectArray addObject:obj];
    [obj release]; //If not using ARC
}
```

Comment: Or the short-hand form `[MyObject new]`. Also: release it when you're done with it (in this example before the `}`) unless using ARC.

Comment: @WTP Both very valid points. I added the `release` just in case anyone not using ARC references this answer.