# Create an array of struct and clear it?

Tags: objective-c

I have following struct

```
typedef struct {
    double x;
    double y;
} Point;
```

I want to create an array of it with defined size and clear it use this code:

```
Point *temppoints = new Point[pointCounts];
delete []temppoints;
```

However Xcode won't compile because of the `new` and `delete`.

Any advise?

Comment: Did you read any C book before starting to write the code?

Comment: @SeekAddo lol honestly no, because mainly I will do the code in Objective-C, very rarely to use C code

Comment: lol. i see, because this things are basically well explained in the books.

Comment: Try an earlier answer from the stack (as it were). Also, apple University has entire courses online re objective C and Xcode. [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8748114/new-and-delete-command-of-c-in-obj-c)

Comment: That's not C. Don't spam tags.

Comment: @Olaf It's not Objective-C either.

Comment: @maddy: No, but according to a comment OP intends to use it. Not sure how to allocate memory in ObjC, though; AFAIK it has a garbage collection, so `malloc` does not make much sense, does it? I VtC as unclear; OP might want to read a book about the basics before starting whatever he intends.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `new` and `delete` keywords are C++ only.  If you're using C, you need to use the `malloc` and `free` functions:

```
Point *temppoints = malloc(pointCounts * sizeof(Point));
...
free(temppoints);
```