# Access class variable in object C

Tags: objective-c

I’m a newer in Objective C.  I found can access the private variable outside. I just get a warning Like follows:

```
@interface foo : NSObject
{
   @private 
        int b;
}
-(id) init;
@end
//omit the implement
int main()
{
    foo *a = [[foo alloc] init];
    printf("%d", a->b);
}
```

So dose the private keyword  only work on its subclass?  If Yes, why need protected keyword

Comment: it should be 'a->b' in your code

Comment: First of all, you don't just get a warning, you get an error on the modern compiler (you got a warning with gcc years ago). Also, the code above wouldn't have even compiled in gcc because you've create your own root class, which has no alloc method. Finally, you're trying to access an instance variable on the class itself (which also would have caused an error, even under gcc).

Comment: I'm sorry. I was supposed to write a->b

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you provided accesses `ab`, not `b`. Furthermore, you're using the class name `foo`, but you appear to be trying to access an instance variable named `ab`. If you want to access an instance variable, you'll first need to create an instance of the class:

```
foo f = [foo new];
```

The `@private` keyword prevents you from accessing `b` from anywhere other than the methods defined by class `foo`.

**Update:**

> I'm assure the codes is correct now. So why I can access the variable outside.

If you're compiling with an Objective-C compiler, you normally can't:

[image: Private variable error image]

If you're able to get the code to compile and access `b`, there's something odd going on. What compiler are you using, and what settings?

Comment: I'm really sorry. I made a mistake on writing. Please read it again.

Comment: As a matter of general Objective-C syntax, it is generally a good idea to avoid use of `new`: cf. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719877/use-of-alloc-init-instead-of-new-objective-c

Comment: @AlexReynolds In fact, I always use alloc/init myself, but new seems to better make my point here that you need to create a new instance of foo. I don't agree that one should *avoid* new -- it's in most respects the same thing and basically comes down to a matter of style. Probably the best reason to prefer alloc/init is that it's just more common these days.

Comment: Hi I'm sorry for my carelessness. I'm assure the codes is correct now. So why I can access the variable outside .