# Calling a method from another class in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, class, methods, call

I'm trying to get to grips with Objective-C, having programmed in Java and C in the past.

I have a class, Unzip, which contains the following method:

`- (void)unzipFile:(NSString*)fileName`

I'm trying to call this method from the AppDelegate class, to respond to a button click, using the following code, which creates an instance of Unzip and calls the unzipFile method with a string value, but nothing happens.

```
- (IBAction)unzipIt:(id)sender {
    NSLog(@"Unzip clicked");
    NSString *zipString = [_testField stringValue];

    NSLog(@"Calling unzip with the string %@", zipString);
    Unzip *unzip;
    [unzip unzipFile:(zipString)]; 
}
```

The actual button click works, because the two initial NSLogs appear, but nothing further happens. The method is fine as I've tested it elsewhere so at least **something** should happen. Could anybody please tell me where I'm going wrong?

Thanks for your time.

Comment: You aren't creating an instance, just declaring a pointer to one. Do `Unzip *unzip = [[Unzip alloc] init];` instead, to actually instantiate one.

Comment: you never init unzip. that wouldn't work in java or C either

Comment: @Daij-Djan Except in Java or C, there would at least be a runtime error.

Comment: @MikeD yes. objective-C doesn't do nullPointerExceptions

Comment: if that is bad, I don't know

Comment: @Daij-Djan Just pointing out a difference for the OP.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You didn't allocate `Unzip`:

```
Unzip *unzip = [[Unzip alloc] init];
[unzip unzipFile:zipString];
```

The reason why it is not working, but not blowing up, is in Objective C, it is safe to send a message to `nil`.

Some [more concepts about Objective C](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/WorkingwithObjects/WorkingwithObjects.html), especially in the section **Working with Nil**.

Comment: Ah, how stupid of me. Thanks.

Comment: @MarkRandell No worries. Coming from Java or C, you expect something like this to either not compile, or throw exceptions at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

You have to initialize your `unzip` variable

```
Unzip *unzip = [[Unzip alloc] init];
```

There is also a shortcut:

```
Unzip *unzip = [Unzip new];
```

which is equivalent shorthand.

Comment: dont call new, the convention is alloc + init OR a convenience method of your own..

Comment: @Daij-Djan Why is that?

Comment: @JoshHudnall It's preference more than anything.  Some people believe that new is the easy way out, and that it may have side-effects.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719877/use-of-alloc-init-instead-of-new-objective-c

Comment: @Daij-Djan From my research, it is equivalent to [[alloc] init]. Even Apple use it in certain instances. From what I understand, it is a matter of personal preference.

Comment: I think that new should have never been part of the Lang spec, but I can see why they included it with the whole of NSObject being built on C++.

Comment: Yeah, I saw that answer, but the only even halfway valid reason I can see is that more explicit is better, but I don't feel that to be a true statement in every case. Either way, both work. :)