# Difference between [[UIImageView new] init] and [[UIImageView alloc] init]

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimageview, uikit, alloc

I am just wonder what is the difference between [[UIImageView new] init] and [[UIImageView alloc] init] .

is memory allocated in [[UIImageView new] init] as well ?

Comment: Well, what did the documentation say?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Use of alloc init instead of new](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/719877/use-of-alloc-init-instead-of-new)

Answer (score 3):

`+ new` is equivalent with `+ alloc` followed by `- init`, so

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView alloc] init];
```

and

```
UIImageView *iv = [UIImageView new];
```

are right (and equivalent) and

```
UIImageView *iv = [[UIImageView new] init];
```

is **wrong,** since it calls `- init` twice.

Comment: will new] init]  compile?  I didn't try.

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Why wouldn't it?

Comment: I assumed compiler to be intelligent, and it should avoid leak, two init in one line (In ARC, it is fine) but in MRC leak is probable, isn't it?

Comment: @AnoopVaidya Compiler has no knowledge of runtime... And yes, calling `init` twice does very well have the risk of leaking memory.

Comment: A doubled (or more) call to -init doesn't call through to retain.  There will never be a memory leak.  Memory management semantics reside in assignment and allocator functions, but that's it.

Comment: @CodaFi Huh what? What if I do `_someIvar = [[Foo alloc] init];` inside `- init`? Like [this](https://github.com/H2CO3/HCDownload/blob/master/HCDownloadViewController.m#l45)?

Comment: Retention occurs because the +1 initialized object is assigned to an implicitly strong local (+2).  ARC should balance that out to +1

Comment: @CodaFi And if I don't use ARC? (Hey, you **know** I don't!)

Comment: Then the initialized variable is assigned to an implicitly `assign` local, and it remains +1.  If you go through the setter, then you have to autorelease it back down to +1

Comment: @CodaFi Yes, that's right. That's why I pointed you to a line where it does **not** go through the setter :) Let's agree on that both of us are right ;)