# The use of autorelease?

Tags: objective-c

I am not clear about how to use `autorelease`;

```
NSAutoreleasePool* pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
RetainTracker* tracker = [RetainTracker new];
[tracker retain];
[tracker retain];
[tracker autorelease];
[pool release];
```

Is there any memory leak in the above code?

I know the `autorelease` just puts `tracker` into `NSAutoreleasePool`, without modifying the reference count for `tracker`. When i call `[pool release]`, the object receives one message `release`, then the reference count of `tracker` is `2`. So the compiler can't call the `dealloc` function of object `tracker`, so there is a memory leak.

So i get this: we shoul call `retain` and `release` same times, is it right?

Comment: Not sure what `RetainTracker` is, but you retain twice then only autorelease once, so yes, it will leak (unless `RetainTracker` has funny behaviour). `autorelease` is just like calling `release` as far as final retain count goes, it just waits until the pool is released before applying. You can use it to keep temporaries alive for long enough in statements.

Comment: Just as an aside, I favour the Objective-C 2.0 `@autorelease { … }`, as the scope is clearer.

Comment: +1 for asking a good question and having me re-read memory management docs again for the first time in a long time.

Comment: It's actually retained 3 times, the `new` and the two `retain`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[new is equivalent to doing an "alloc" & "init"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/720063/981049), so retain count on tracker on that line is 1.

Then you increment the retain count 2 more times to give a total retain count of 3.

Autorelease sets the tracker to be released when the pool is released ([and the retain count is decremented as well](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/autorelease)).  But it's already retained 3 times, so it doesn't really get released.

And yeah, there is a memory leak with the retain count being greater than 0 and no reference to "`tracker`" outside of that method (that is, unless you're using "`tracker`" in an instance variable).

It's very good to know the basics of memory management; but if you want to save yourself a ton of headache, just do what everyone else here seems to be saying and simply enable ARC.

EDIT:  And to finish your question, you should make sure every call to *retain* is balanced with a *release*.  You also do a "`new`", which also increments the retain count so you need to "`release`" because of that as well.

Comment: I don't see any reason this should crash, unless it gets called millions upon millions of times and fills the memory…

Comment: Yeah, maybe not a crash but definitely a nice leak.

Comment: It gets released, it wont get deallocated.

Comment: yep, not with a retain count of 3 it won't.  +1 to your answer.

Comment: "so it doesn't really get released" you mean it doesn't get deallocated

Comment: it only gets released once the retain count hits zero, but we're not seeing that in the code snippet up above.

Comment: No, it only gets *deallocated* if every referencing object *releases* it. Releasing an object means the retain count drops, not necessarily to zero. its confusing to mix the terminology, keep it straight pleasethxbye

Answer (score 4):

If you're new to Objective-c, you should be using Automatic Reference Counting. Almost everyone should. But for the sake of understanding:

An object has a reference count of how many objects have a reference to it. When it drops to zero, the object is not referenced by anything and is deallocated. Every method in Objective-C is responsible for releasing any object it retains. The problem is, if a factory method's job is to create an object, it's breaking the rules by not releasing an object it retained (in this example it was retained because it was created). If the method called `release` on the object right before returning it, it would be returning the address to an object that is already gone. So, there is autorelease, which temporarily delays the release until the calling method can retain the object the called method created.

In your example above, if you got rid of the 2 retains, and only called autorelease, then the object would get released and deallocated when the autorelease pool is released and (right before deallocation) is drained, meaning it calls release on all objects in its pool, tracker being one of them because calling autorelease on tracker added it to the pool.